# how to evaluate json response from meme api in html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to implement this API into my website so I can get random memes from reddit.

The API was made by D3vd on github (https://www.github.com/D3vd/Meme_API)

The response I get from https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/memes (the api) looks something like this:

```
{
    "postLink": "https://redd.it/sg8j7b",
    "subreddit": "memes",
    "title": "No you respect the nature now!",
    "url": "https://i.redd.it/nk9eiy1nnte81.jpg",
    "nsfw": false,
    "spoiler": false,
    "author": "Abdul_Sbeei",
    "ups": 423,
    "preview": ["https://preview.redd.it/nk9eiy1nnte81.jpg?width=108\u0026crop=smart\u0026auto=webp\u0026s=253fc41547e5acc1ee3efcc0a4644e8d52d67181", "https://preview.redd.it/nk9eiy1nnte81.jpg?width=216\u0026crop=smart\u0026auto=webp\u0026s=6050660429dd3a4ae6699a0f42294c04fc1fae02", "https://preview.redd.it/nk9eiy1nnte81.jpg?width=320\u0026crop=smart\u0026auto=webp\u0026s=07ff549bbd76d2f25f509cece0149e7939427edd", "https://preview.redd.it/nk9eiy1nnte81.jpg?width=640\u0026crop=smart\u0026auto=webp\u0026s=baa9e058ba9722515aefa9ab28bb95235d0e151b"]
}
```

How do I get only the image link ("url") with javascript, so that I can display it on my website?

thx in advance

Comment: `yourResponseObject.url`...

Comment: In Javascript, keys are accessed using obj.key 
For eg let obj = {a: 'test'}; console.log(obj.a); // This will print test
In case of your API response, you can say obj.url

Comment: Pls show the code you are using to get an API data

Comment: i got that output by going to the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some very basic ajax code using fetch should suffice:

```js
fetch('https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/memes')
  .then(r=>r.json())
  .then(json=>{
    console.log( json.url )
  })
```

Comment: this is the best approach taught you were limited to the object

Comment: is it possible to save those images on the server after being loaded?

Comment: Yes it is possible. To do so using `fetch` initially to get the json data would be convoluted and inefficient. Assuming that whatever server you have for your website has PHP or similar language you would probably want to use a technique where the json is downloaded by the server (cURL, file_get_contents or other ), processed by the server (save files at this stage) and send something to the browser